# How can I get digit after 0 with php

Tags: php, regex

I have an number with the following format.
100034,
100345,
103456,

I want to get any digit after 0 like this.
34,
345,
3456

How can I get?Help me plz.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 4):

How about using modulo maths:

```
$str = '103456';

$n = (int) $str % pow(10, strlen($str)-1); // 3456
```

Comment: What an elegant solution: convert to int and get everything except the 1-st 1. Leading zeroes will be removed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression with capturing group:

```
<?php
$str = "103456";

$matches = array();
preg_match('/^10+(.*)/', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Prints:

```
string(4) "3456"
```

Comment: I'd add an anchor, just to be sure: `/^10+(.*)/`

Comment: @n3rd Answer improved

Comment: Why using regex when there is more better functions?

Comment: @bystwn22 Yes, string functions will be faster here. But as a possible solution, we can use it.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
$n = 1000444;  
$str = end(explode('0', $n));  
echo $str;
```

it works for 100003456 or any other number like this

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "100000024";
preg_match('/[^0]*$/', $string, $matches);

// Output
array (size=1)
  0 => string '24' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using substr() and strrpos()

```
$digit = "100034";
echo substr($digit, strrpos($digit, '0')+1); //34
```

Answer (score 0):

And one more solution for good measure:

```
ltrim(substr($str, 1), '0')
```

Comment: You have an extra bracket at the end

Comment: Oops, c&p error :) thanks